# Correlated Bernoulli Model

Tags: probability

If I have two non-independent Bernoulli variables X1 and X2, and E(X1) = E(X2) = r, and the correlation between X1 and X2 is q, how do I model the sum of the two variables?

If it helps, I'm trying to derive the distribution for when the sum of the two variables is equal to zero. This is the distribution I'm trying to arrive at:

> Pr(X1 + X2 = 0) = (1 - r)^2 + r(1 - r)q

Comment: Have you looked up anything about the correlation of Bernoulli variables and how that relates to its joint probabilities? What have you gotten stuck on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting stuck on deriving the sum of two dependent Bernoulli variables.

Comment: Do you know the mean and variance for a Bernoulli variable? Do you know the formula for the covariance or correlation of two random variables?

Comment: Yes, we have looked at these formulas. My main question is how the correlation of the Bernoulli variables fits into the sum of two non independent variables. If they are independant, then the sum is binomially distributed. But what if they are not? How do you derive that formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bernoulli variables only ever take the values 0 and 1, $X_1 + X_2 = 0$ is the same event as $X_1 = X_2 = 0$, so you're trying to find the probability of that event, i.e. $P(X_1 = 0 \land X_2 = 0)$.

To save space, I'm going to use some shorthand for some events:

| Event | Notation |
| --- | --- |
| $X_1 = a \land X_2 = b$ | $ab$ |
| $X_1 = a$ | $a \cdot$ |
| $X_2 = b$ | $\cdot b$ |

So in this notation we're interested in finding $P(00)$. We already know that $E(X_i) = r$ and $Var(X_i) = r(1-r)$, so next we need to find an expression for the correlation.

We can write the covariance of the two variables as:

$\begin{eqnarray}\textrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2) & = & E(X_1 X_2) - E(X_1) E(X_2) \\
& = & (1 \times P(X_1 X_2 = 1) + 0 \times P(X_1 X_2 = 0)) - r \times r \\
& = & P(11) - r^2
\end{eqnarray}$

since $X_1 X_2 = 1$ only happens when $X_1 = X_2 = 1$. Then the formula for correlation is

$\begin{eqnarray} \rho_{X_1 X_2} & = & \frac{\textrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2)}{\sigma_{X_1} \sigma_{X_2}} \\
q & = & \frac{P(11) - r^2}{\sqrt{Var(X_1) Var(X_2)}} \\
& = & \frac{P(11) - r^2}{r(1 - r)}
\end{eqnarray}$

Then, rearranging, you get $P(11) = r^2 + qr(1 - r)$, so we now have the probability of both variables equalling 1 in relation to the two parameters.

You're looking for $P(00)$, so you need to break down the marginal probabilities, specifically you can use $r = P(1 \cdot) = P(10) + P(11)$ and $1 - r = P(\cdot 0) = P(10) + P(00)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! It makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Define , $Y_1:=1-X_1$ and $Y_2:=1-X_2$.   Identify how these variables are distributed and correlated, then use this to fill in the elipsis:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1+X_2=0) &= \mathsf P(Y_1+Y_2=2)\\ &=\mathsf P(Y_1=1,Y_2=1)\\ &~~\vdots\\&=qr(1-r)+(1-r)^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm still a bit confused where the correlation q comes in

Comment: The correlation equals the covariance divided by the square root of the product of the variances of the Bernoulli random variables

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!